# NodeJS fork process is slowing down all other forked processes when I start new one

Tags: node.js, performance, imagemagick, multiprocessing, fork

I have a `NodeJS` program which creates an image from some text in my db using `ImageMagick`. The program is lunched from my `NodeJs` server using

```
import childProcess from 'child_process';
let args = [':imageId', '--max_old_space_size=4096'];
childProcess.fork('createImage.js', args);
```

The process of creating an image is quite slow it may takes 5-6min on my local machine for single image with size 114x84cm.

I will try to explain what is happening in program life cycle.

So, I have server which is running on process `MyServer`, when someone request an image `MyServer` forks a new process.

The new process `ImageCreator1` has a loop from promises and will wait until all are resolved. Each promise creates a part of that big image using `ImageMagick`

In my activity monitor I can see that there are some running processes

```
Process Name   |  %CPU
MyServer       -  0.3
ImageCreator1  -  30.0
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.2
convert        -  0.1
```

Also I can see that `ImageCreator1` running async 4-5 `ImageMagick` convert processes to create all this required small images.

This all will take like 5min. to create the big image.

So when I start two `ImageCreators` the time is increased to 9min.

```
Process Name   |  %CPU
MyServer       -  0.3
ImageCreator1  -  30.0
ImageCreator2  -  40.0
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.2
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.1
convert        -  0.2
convert        -  0.1
```

and If I start `ImageCreator3` or `ImageCreator4` is getting slower and slower. I was thinking that when I start a new process and if this process is finishing the job for 5min. Then if I start five processes simultaneity each of them has to finish for 5min. but seems that with each new `ImageCreator` the time for all is increased.

I am still in learning stage with `NodeJs` and this `OS` stuff, so if some one can explain what's going on would be great.

!!! UPDATE IMAGECREATOR CODE !!!

```
console.time('imageCreator');
process.title = 'imageCreator'+process.argv[2];

const fs = require('fs');
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick:true});
const Promise = require('bluebird');

var images = [], rows = [];
for(var i = 1; i<=100;i++){
    images.push(i);
}

for(var i = 1; i<=10;i++){

    rows.push(Promise.reduce(images, function(total, image){

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            gm('xc:rgb('+(image*2)+','+image+','+(image*2)+')')
            .in('-units', 'PixelsPerInch')
            .in('-size', '100x100')
            .in('-density', 300)
            .in('-page', '+'+(image-100)*100+'+0')
            .toBuffer('miff', function(err, stream){
                    fs.appendFile(__dirname+'/test'+process.argv[2]+'.miff', stream, function(err){
                        if(err) reject(err);
                        else resolve(image);
                    });
            });

        });

    }));

}


Promise.all(rows).then(function( ) {
    console.timeEnd('imageCreator');
});
```

So I was doing some tests to find out what part of my script is problematic. Here is an example what's is happening when I run this on my mac. By the way I did recompile ImageMagick so now I have:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-2 Q16 x86_64 2017-01-03 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

So when I run the script above on one terminal I get the time like:

```
Terminal1 - imageCreator: 7498.438ms - 7.4984380002sec.
```

But when I try on two terminals at same time:

```
Terminal1 - imageCreator: 14632.522ms - 14.632522sec.
Terminal2 - imageCreator: 13734ms - 13.734sec.
```

As you can see the time is almost doubled for both.

My computer has:

```
processor:2.7 GHz Intel Core i5
memory:8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
```

so what's going on, I guess the ram is involved here but I am not very good with this low level stuff so if someone can explain it would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Saying an image is 114cm x 84cm doesn't tell us much - at a `dpi` of 1 that would be 9,000 pixels but at 600dpi it would be 3,500,000,000 pixels.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the `dpi` of the image is 300dpi, but is this really matter? Let's say if I have process running and converting an image with 72dpi and while this process is running I start another one the time for both is increased. I don't know if the problem is in ImageMagick or nodejs, need to do bit more tests, I will try what @rdegges shared link suggest compile ImageMagick with  --disable-openmp and will simulate my nodejs program running without ImageMagick and will post the result. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What I mean is, 114cm x 84cm is 45inches x 33 inches. So at 300 dpi, your image will have 45*300*33*300 pixels, i.e. 133 Megapixels. If it is colour, with 3 channels (RGB) and 16-bit/pixel, you will need to multiply that by 6, so it will need 800MB of RAM for each image, minimum. Maybe you should show the code in `ImageCreator` and look at the RAM limits on your process as you may be paging out to disk.

Comment: Hi @Mark Setchell as you suggested I updated my question with some test code which is behaving the same. I am running my node program with 
`node test.js 1 --max_old_space_size=4096` which is 4gb for the process

Answer (score 1):

How many CPU cores does the computer you're executing this code on have? When you create a new process with `child_process`, you're starting a new process -- this means the OS scheduler will attempt to run the new process in parallel to your parent process -- but this *requires* multiple CPUs.

If you don't have multiple CPUs, what will happen is that the OS scheduler will start swapping between running your main process, and your child process and give each of them CPU time on the same CPU, thereby not really running them in 'parallel' since only one instruction will be executed at any given time.

Another thing to be careful of is ImageMagick: is it safe to run in multiple processes?

I'm not very familiar with ImageMagick, but according to [this old thread](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14307) from 2009 (this may very well be different nowadays), ImageMagick uses its own threading: so running it concurrently in multiple processes will NOT result in any speedup.

Hope that helps!